# TrainReservation markup has no effect on the email

Tags: google-schemas

We are trying to integrate `TrainReservation` schemas in our emails, like what we did for `FlightReservation` before. I've tried sending a test email to myself (using google scripts) along with the following schema:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
     [
          {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "TrainReservation",
            "reservationNumber": "175091993",
            "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed",
            "cancelReservationUrl": "https://test.com/cancel?id=AB3XY2",
            "underName": {
              "@type": "Person",
              "name": "Test Test"
            },
            "reservationFor": {
              "@type": "TrainTrip",
              "departureStation": {
                    "@type": "TrainStation",
                    "name": "Foo"
              },
              "departureTime": "2021-09-21T15:15:00+04:30",
              "arrivalStation": {
                "@type": "TrainStation",
                "name": "Bar"
              },
              "arrivalTime": "2021-09-21T19:55:00+04:30",
              "trainNumber": "282"
            },
            "reservedTicket": {
                "@type": "Ticket",
                "underName": "Test Test",
                "ticketNumber": "175091993",
                "additionalTicketText": "Some text"
            }
          }
      ]
</script>
```

The schema is successfully tested using the markup tester. However, in the received email, I do not see any special thing, unlike `FlightReservation` markups that show the itinerary data at the top of the email, adds it to the calendar automatically and has action buttons for cancellation and modification.

So I'm wondering, am I doing something wrong, or is this just the normal behavior? What features do I have to expect from `TrainReservation` markups for the receivers of emails? (and also please answer that for `BusReservation` markups as well)

Comment: 10 days passed without any answers. Good job guys at GOOGLE!

Comment: 26 days passed without any answers. Good job guys at GOOGLE!

Comment: 322 days passed without any answers. Good job guys at GOOGLE! (Actually I've forgotten that I had this question some day, and it is STILL unanswered for me here or anywhere else. More important question is, when they do not want to answer questions here, why do they encourage people to ask here in their documentation?)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this question is almost a year old, but it appeared when I Googled "TrainReservation" and "Schema" and didn't have any answers. Somebody asked it 6 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198257/trainreservation-markup-has-no-effect-on-the-email), and it looks like as of **August 2022** the TrainReservation type is **not supported** in Google Schema - you can find [a list of supported schema types here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/google-now#supported_schemas), which currently only includes:

- Events
- Flights
- Hotels
- Restaurants

They haven't included [car hire](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rental-car), but that does also seem to work in my experience.

I suppose all we can do is wait for Google to eventually implement TrainReservation and BusReservation as types. Very frustrating!

Comment: It IS supported in Gmail actually, according to https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview#gmail_highlights.

Comment: That's certainly what I thought too, but as far as I've been able to, it just plain won't appear - have you had any more luck in the intervening year at getting it to show up? Following their tutorials to the letter doesn't produce anything at all, and neither does fiddling about with various data types, even when their validator suggests it's fully compatible, and items like Flights, events and car hire work flawlessly.